# 18.04 upgrade problem

Tags: 18.04, unity, upgrade

So I do sudo apt update and it updates saying I need to upgrade 5 packages. So I do sudo apt upgrade and it says and it keeps saying 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded. Below is what i do and i keep getting this

```
    sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apt-xapian-index dmidecode gconf-service gconf-service-backend
  gconf2 gconf2-common gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0
  laptop-detect libcurl3 libgconf-2-4 libgnome-keyring-common
  libgnome-keyring0 libnih-dbus1 libplymouth4 libpython-stdlib
  plymouth plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text python python-apt
  python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-asn1crypto
  python-attr python-automat python-blinker python-bs4 python-cairo
  python-cffi-backend python-chardet python-click python-colorama
  python-constantly python-cryptography python-cups python-dbus
  python-debian python-defer python-dirspec python-enum34 python-gi
  python-gi-cairo python-html5lib python-httplib2 python-hyperlink
  python-idna python-incremental python-ipaddress python-jwt
  python-lxml python-minimal python-oauthlib python-openssl
  python-pam python-piston-mini-client python-pkg-resources
  python-pyasn1 python-pyasn1-modules python-serial
  python-service-identity python-six python-twisted-bin
  python-twisted-core python-twisted-web python-webencodings
  python-xapian python-xdg python-zope.interface python2.7
  python2.7-minimal python3-piston-mini-client python3-xapian
  software-center-aptdaemon-plugins
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-evdev
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-wacom
  xserver-xorg-video-intel
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exact text of all error messages. Do not post a screen shot, copy and paste the text.

Comment: You need to run `sudo apt full-upgrade` to update the kernel and a few other things.

Comment: it did not work

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
`sudo apt-get autoremove`
`sudo apt-get autoclean`

or as a one liner

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean`